# Weird side effects with Tikz positioning library

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, chronology

I use Tikz and chronology in a paper.
However, as soon as I use the Tikz positioning library, I observe weird side effects.
I can solve this problem if I remove the positioning library (and include it everywhere, which is not intended, I'd say).
Why is that and how to correctly use these libraries and prevent such side effects?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,positioning} % remove 'positioning' for correct result
% http://i.imgur.com/DJNlDtv.jpg

\usepackage{chronology}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{chronology}[1]{1998}{2008}{7ex}{1\textwidth}
\event[1999]{2002}{ABC}
\event[2003]{2006}{DEF}
\event[2006]{2008}{GHI}
\end{chronology}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JlDiaz Reported and fixed point [1](https://github.com/lwiseman/chronology/issues/1) and [2](https://github.com/lwiseman/chronology/issues/2). Please feel free to contribute if necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug which has been fixed in version 1.1.1 of the package `chronology`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, `chronology` is using a deprecated form of `right` keyword, and`positioning` library redefines it. This explains why chronology's output changes when `positioning` package is included.

Second, IMHO the positioning of the text over the timeline made by chronology is not good. It includes `right=0.5\unit` for each label, which causes that labe to be shifted to the right, and thus it does not appear over the intended date.

This can be clearly seen in your example. Labels ABC, DEF, and GHI are supposed to be centered on top of the dates they span (the gray bars below them), but clearly they are not. Apparently this is intentional, because chronolgy shifts them throught  the `right` option mentioned, but I cannot understand why.

This is especially notorious when you use "single point" dates instead of ranges of dates. For example:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{chronology}[1]{1998}{2008}{7ex}{1\textwidth}
\event{2003}{Foo}
\event[2003]{2004}{Bar}
\end{chronology}
\end{figure}
```

Produces:

[image: Result]

IMHO the horizontal displacement makes the timeline difficult to read. It is label Foo refering to 2003 (it is) or to the range 2003-2004? (this is what it looks like)

I propose the following fix. Add this to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\event}[3][e]{%
  \pgfmathsetlength\xstop{(#2-\theyearstart)*\unit}%
  \ifx #1e%
    \draw[fill=black,draw=none,opacity=0.5]%
      (\xstop, 0) circle (.2\unit)%
      node[anchor=south west, yshift=.2\unit,rotate=45,opacity=1] {#3};%
  \else%
    \pgfmathsetlength\xstart{(#1-\theyearstart)*\unit}%
    \draw[fill=black, opacity=0.5,rounded corners=.2\unit]%
      (\xstart,-.2\unit) rectangle%
      node[anchor=south west, yshift=.2\unit,rotate=45,opacity=1] {#3} (\xstop,.2\unit);%
  \fi}%
```

Using this preamble, the output is now:

[image: Result]

Which (IMHO) looks more natural.

In addition, my code produces the same result with or without `positioning` library, because it does not use the conflicting `right` keyword.

If you want the labels shifted to the right (just like `chronology` makes them by default), you can add the option `xshift=0.5\unit` to each `node` of the `\event`  definition.

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed in version 1.1.1 of this package.

Please note that there is a new syntax since 1.1 which looks like:

```
#1 (optional) = stepsize, 
#2 = yearstart, 
#3 = yearstop, 
#4 = postscaledtimelinewidth, 
#5 (optional) = prescaledtimelinewidth
```

The code for your and JLDiaz' example looks like the following:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{chronology}[1]{1998}{2008}{\textwidth}
            \event[1999]{2002}{ABC}
            \event[2003]{2006}{DEF}
            \event[2006]{2008}{GHI}
        \end{chronology}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{chronology}[1]{1998}{2008}{\textwidth}
            \event{2003}{Foo}
            \event[2003]{2004}{Bar}
        \end{chronology}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

and results in:

[image]